# Swapping out one index for another in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am running Elasticsearch on a personal machine that only has so much memory. I'd like to use all of the memory at any given time for whatever problem I'm working on, but make it easy to switch between projects.

For example, I have a project involving a large text corpus, and a different project with geospatial data. I'd like to switch Elasticsearch from indexing one to the other without reindexing all the documents.

Is there an easier way to do this than to do a backup/reload of the index?

Answer (score 1):

ES has open/close index API:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/my_index/_close'

curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/my_index/_open'
```